# Combine list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have a list of 6 dictionaries:

```
[{'fruit':'Apple', 'Color':'red', 'weight':'10'},
 {'fruit':'Banana', 'Color':'yellow', 'weight':'20'},
 {'fruit':'Kiwi', 'Color':'Green', 'weight':'15'},
 {'Veggie':'Onion', 'Color':'white', 'price':'10'},
 {'Veggie':'Cabbage', 'Color':'Light Green', 'price':'30'},
 {'Leafy':'Spinach', 'Color':'Dark Green', 'quantity':'30'}]
```

I need to convert it into:

```
[{'Fruit':[Apple, Banana, Kiwi], 'Color':[red, yellow, green], 'weight':[10,20,15]},
 {'Veggie':[Onion, Cabbage], 'Color':[white, light green], 'price':[10,30]},
 {'Leafy':[Spinach], 'Color':[Dark Green], 'quantity':[30]}]
```

I tried multiple logics- comparing consecutive dictionaries, using map to keep a track of dictionaries with same keys but none of it is working. Can someone please advise on the code logic? Thank you

Comment: [Edit] the question to show the code you are having a problem with, the current output, and the desired output.

Comment: what have you tried so far

Comment: Given an arbitrary element `d` from the list, how do you know which key(s) you are looking for to create the grouping you want? Is `Fruit`, `Veggie`, `Leafy` something you are given?

Comment: No this is just an example.. I’m looking to combine the dictionaries by their set of keys. If the set of keys is different then it will go as a separate entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
lst = [
    {"fruit": "Apple", "Color": "red", "weight": "10"},
    {"fruit": "Banana", "Color": "yellow", "weight": "20"},
    {"fruit": "Kiwi", "Color": "Green", "weight": "15"},
    {"Veggie": "Onion", "Color": "white", "price": "10"},
    {"Veggie": "Cabbage", "Color": "Light Green", "price": "30"},
    {"Leafy": "Spinach", "Color": "Dark Green", "quantity": "30"},
]

out = {}
for d in lst:
    out.setdefault(frozenset(d), []).append(d)

out = [{kk: [d[kk] for d in v] for kk in k} for k, v in out.items()]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {
        "Color": ["red", "yellow", "Green"],
        "fruit": ["Apple", "Banana", "Kiwi"],
        "weight": ["10", "20", "15"],
    },
    {
        "Color": ["white", "Light Green"],
        "price": ["10", "30"],
        "Veggie": ["Onion", "Cabbage"],
    },
    {"Color": ["Dark Green"], "Leafy": ["Spinach"], "quantity": ["30"]},
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.groupby` with the set of dictionary keys as the grouping key.  This assumes similarly keyed dictionaries are already listed together as in the example, but you can ensure they are sorted by same sets of keys with `org_list.sort(key=sorted)`.

```py
from pprint import pprint
from itertools import groupby

org_list = [{'fruit':'Apple', 'Color':'red', 'weight':'10'},
            {'fruit':'Banana', 'Color':'yellow', 'weight':'20'},
            {'fruit':'Kiwi', 'Color':'Green', 'weight':'15'},
            {'Veggie':'Onion', 'Color':'white', 'price':'10'},
            {'Veggie':'Cabbage', 'Color':'Light Green', 'price':'30'},
            {'Leafy':'Spinach', 'Color':'Dark Green', 'quantity':'30'}]

result_list = []
for group_key, group in groupby(org_list, key=set):
    group_dict = {}  # new dict to collect a similar key set
    for dct in group:
        for key, value in dct.items():
            if key not in group_dict:
                group_dict[key] = [value]  # start a new key list
            else:
                group_dict[key].append(value)  # append to existing key
    result_list.append(group_dict)  # finished with that key set

pprint(result_list, width=120)
```

Output:

```
[{'Color': ['red', 'yellow', 'Green'], 'fruit': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Kiwi'], 'weight': ['10', '20', '15']},
 {'Color': ['white', 'Light Green'], 'Veggie': ['Onion', 'Cabbage'], 'price': ['10', '30']},
 {'Color': ['Dark Green'], 'Leafy': ['Spinach'], 'quantity': ['30']}]
```

Comment: @nocomment Or use defaultdict, or .setdefault().  Six of one, half dozen of the other.